# To count the number of weeks between two dates in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have used the below query to find the number of weeks between two dates:

```
select  count(week_id) 
from fw 
where week_begin_date >= '2015-01-01' 
and  week_end_date <= '2015-12-31';
```

Expected result should be 53 but the actual result is 51.

Kindly help on this.

Comment: How about `count(*)` instead of `week_id`. Does that also give you 51? Or does it give you 53?

Comment: what is the datatype of "week_begin_date " and "week_end_date "?

Comment: You access a table called "fw" .. however, you've not provided the structure, nor any hint as to what the data looks like in there.  We cannot possible answer your question until you provide that information.

Comment: How do you define `number of weeks`? The result depends on when a week begins and ends (monday to sunday or sunday to saturday)

Comment: Are you talking calendar weeks? Or actual weeks? From today to next tuesday is one week that spans two calendar weeks, so the answers one or two could be acceptable depending on the specific rule you are calculating.

Comment: I hate to say this, but it's very likely all of the above + full week requirement from a table called FW (which I'm guessing means "full week".  Unless the first of January is the first day of the week and the 31st of December is the last day of the week, you won't get a valid answer.  So the ">=" component will probably eliminate the first week and the "<=" will eliminate the last.  Hence "I expected 53 and got 51".

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just use the week of year function? subtract if needed...

```
 select to_char(to_date('12/31/2015','MM/DD/YYYY'),'WW') from dual;


select To_Number(to_char(to_date('12/31/2015','MM/DD/YYYY'),'WW')) - 
       To_number(to_char(to_date('01/01/2015','MM/DD/YYYY'),'WW')) +1
from dual;
```

We have to add +1 because weeks start at 1 not 0.

[image]

Now maybe you're after the ISO week format which would be `IW` instead of `WW`.

**WW:** Week of year (1-53) where week 1 starts on the first day of the year and continues to the seventh day of the year.

**IW:** Week of year (1-52 or 1-53) based on the ISO standard.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a very old thread, but I used a modified version of this code today that I thought might be beneficial for someone else. My modification solves for the fractional week issue and the removal of the minus sign:

```
SELECT 
  CEIL(
       ABS(
            (  
               TO_DATE('20160101','YYYYMMDD')
             - TO_DATE('20161231','YYYYMMDD')
            ) / 7 
           )
      ) AS DT
FROM DUAL
```

The ABS function takes the absolute value of the result of subtracting the two dates, thereby eliminating the minus sign if it exists (I switched the order of the dates to demonstrate this). The CEIL function rounds up any fractional week to the next whole week (I changed the year to 2016 to demonstrate this - CEIL is logically equivalent to the ROUNDUP function in Excel). NOTE: We have to apply the ABS function first (inner parenthesis) because CEIL will also round up negative numbers, which would in effect round the weeks down if ABS were applied after CEIL.  The result of this calculation is 53 (subtraction of the dates returns about -52.142857, ABS removes the minus sign, CEIL rounds up to 53).

I hope this ends up being useful to someone.  Thanks.

Comment: Worked as advertised.  Needed to know which way the differences was being calculated, so dropped the ABS.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
SELECT 
  REPLACE(( 
     to_date('20151231','yyyymmdd') - to_date('20150101','yyyymmdd')
  )/7, '-', '')
FROM
  DUAL
```

Comment: Have you tried executing your code? `ORA-01843: not a valid month`

Comment: this results -52 :-)

Comment: The number of days are 365, so number of weeks should be 52 ( @FrankOckenfuss , thanks to point-out the **MINUS-SIGN** )

Comment: Not necessarily true.  2015 started on Thursday; that's week 1 even if it is incomplete. 12/27 was the last week of 2015  that's week 53; also incomplete.  together there's 52 weeks + a fraction of another.  so depending on how you count the fraction there could be 53 weeks.  using the weekofyear function from oracle, you get 53 on 12/31/2015.

Comment: Thanks @xQbert , i also knew this point but did'nt know how to solve this problem. Really thankful for the new learning

Answer (score 0):

Posting below solution for anyone else that still needs this (and note to future self :-) )

I needed to print all the dates between current date's start of week (ISO week .i.e Monday) inclusive of starting and ending period.

We add back an extra week (+7 days), because it'll be one week short otherwise (wouldn't include the starting period). Also included the calculated fields so output for these can be observed simultaneously (but not truly needed)

with wk_range as (
select
trunc(to_date(:endDate,'YYYYMMDD'),'IW') beginWeek,
trunc(sysdate,'IW') endWeek
from dual
)
select
wr.*,
endWeek - beginWeek as daysBetween,
(endWeek - beginWeek + 7)/7 as weeksBetween,
endWeek - (level-1)*7 period_dates
from wk_range wr
connect by level <= ((endWeek - beginWeek +7)/7)